# Is there an option to use a public, trusted CA for Secure Cloud SQL communication?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, certificate-authority

Currently when you create a Cloud SQL instance, a self signed certificate is created per the Google Cloud SQL documentation.

Is there a way to choose a different Certificate Authority so my communications are signed by a trusted third party?

Below is a sample of the current cert created by Google when the instance is created.

Common Name: Google Cloud SQL Server CA
Organization: Google, Inc
Country: US
Valid From: November 26, 2018
Valid To: November 23, 2028
Issuer: Google Cloud SQL Server CA, Google, Inc
Serial Number: 0 (0x0)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your instances using your own CA certificate.

If you have a MySQL instance, follow the steps in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl) of the Google Cloud SQL documentation, where it says *Connect to your Cloud SQL instance using SSL*, but skip the creation of a new client certificate in the beginning.

You need to have the certificate in a text file (such as server-ca.pem) that you'll pass as a flag `--ssl-ca=[CERTIFICATE-FILENAME]` to the `mysql` command.

For PostgreSQL, follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl) instead, again skipping the beginning and using your own CA cert. The cert file would be then indicated when running `psql`, which takes a string as an argument, including `sslrootcert=[CERTIFICATE-FILENAME]` in that string.

Comment: This answer seems misguided. The question is specifically about whether there's a way to configure CloudSQL databases with publicly trusted certificates, which I believe there isn't. If it was possible to use publicly trusted certificates, there would be no need to download the server-ca.pem from Google, but rather you would be able to use a standard CA file probably already existing on your OS file system.